# How to Share Connection String / Config Items between Azure WebApp & Cloud Service?

Tags: azure

I have REST Service hosted as AzureWeb App & Another Cloud-Service WorkerRole, both need to share few common info like DB Connection string / Storage Connection string Etc.,

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is rather broad I will try to answer in a similar way - A good practice in distributed application and micro service architectures is to have services query a single store for their configuration by so allowing your configuration to be consistent and easily changed.

In these cases you would probably want to set up some kind of database known to all services as they initialize. Depending on how complex your config data is, you can decide between several options on Azure:

1. Easy, quick store for simple key value pairs such as strings: consider [Azure Table Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/)
2. For more complex document like configurations (e.g. JSON): consider [DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-introduction/)
3. In some rare cases where latency and throughput is a concern and you might even want to consider an in-memory store such as [Azure Redis cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/), though mostly for configuration data this is an overkill.

Note that all of the suggested services above are Azure managed services meaning you get availability, redundancy and robustness out of the box. This is important since the configuration store you use can be a single point of failure in your system.